# DELETE method for updating the content - is it ok or not?

Tags: sql, rest, api

guys)

I have one question about DELETE method for updating any user info - is it OK to use it if this data will be available after deleting (it will show up) or better to use another method like PUT or PATCH?

Comment: it's probably okay in most cases, but why?

Answer (score 0):

In a rest API `DELETE` method is used to delete resources. So if you mess that up, then the users who use your API would get confused. They would call your `DELETE` API and hope that the specified resource would get deleted.

If you need to update an existing resource use `PUT` or `PATCH`. Use `PUT` method if you need to update resource completely. API may decide to create a new resource is such a resource is not existing. Or use `PATCH` if it's a partial update.